Move files recursively until specific name is reached?
I have a very large amount of files on a desktop that I'm trying to transfer to my laptop. I set up a Sambashare directory on my desktop, mounted it on my laptop, and started copying them. However, over 30 hours into it, my brother closed the lid on my laptop, entirely freezing it.
I need to move every file on the desktop up until the last one that was copied (I ran cp with the -v flag) in the same order as cp so I don't have to start the entire process over again. How can I go about doing this?

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it? Would rather use tools such as rsync or unison that can themselves resume the actual transfer from an arbitrary state.

Well, I already started it, and I'm not exactly able to wait another 30 hours, which is why I asked the question.

rsync can restart at a last known position. also, cp --no-clobber will not [re]copy files already in the destination. take 5 mins to read the cp manpage documentation to familiarise yourself, you will 100% benefit. additionally, you are mixing terms here 'copy' and 'move' are very different, the first 'duplicating' the file onto some other place whereas move is moving it from A to B - very different !

Good file copy utilities, like rsync, can handle this without having to check for file names or anything like that. You've been given some suggestions now; have you had a chance to try these?
